# Accessing SSH tunnel from third machine

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, tunneling

I have set the following ssh tunneling, to access office machine from home:

[execute from office machine] Setup connection Office -> Home (as Home has public IP). Setup reverse tunnel from office machine to home:

```
ssh -CNR 19999:localhost:22 homeuser@home
```

[execute from home machine] Connecting to office from home. Using tunnel from the step 1:

```
ssh -p 19999 officeuser@home
```

Now, how can I access my office machine from a third machine, and not the home one ? I can access my home machine from any machine on the internet.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the SSH documentation for the `-R` parameter:

> By default, TCP listening sockets on the server will be bound to
>                the loopback interface only.  This may be overridden by specify‐
>                ing a bind_address.  An empty bind_address, or the address ‘*’,
>                indicates that the remote socket should listen on all interfaces.
>                Specifying a remote bind_address will only succeed if the
>                server's GatewayPorts option is enabled (see sshd_config(5)).

So you have to use:

```
ssh -CNR 0.0.0.0:19999:localhost:22 homeuser@home
```

If you use OpenSSH `sshd` server on your home server you need to set the `GatewayPorts` option in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to `yes`.

Comment: This answer doesn’t belong: it’s just as off-topic as the question itself. Please don’t encourage off-topic questions by answering them.

Comment: Maybe this is off-topic, but the answer does belong to the question and is the correct solution, sorry.

Comment: To paraphrase the FAQ, [Answer well-asked questions: not all questions can or should be answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It’s off topic because it belongs on another stackexchange site.